# Getting a variable from previous page

Tags: php

So I have a variable from a page:

```
<?php echo $lang['Name']; ?>
```

With some googling, I found out you can use this in order to pass it to the page you want it to pass:

```
<a href='step-3.php?orderName =$lang['Name']'></a>
```

then I use this code to get the variable:

```
$productName = $_GET["orderName"];
```

The problem right now is: Somehow it doesn't show up since when I try to write it in a txt, it doesn't appear(0 tekst). So does it mean it doesn't get passed?

Edit: This is the part of the code I with the variables I want:

```
 <td class="name">
                <?php echo $lang['Name']; ?>
                <a href="order-step-3.php?orderName=<?php echo $lang['Company']; ?>">Details bestelling - Silverman Sachs</a>
              </td>
              <td class="price">
                <em><?php echo $lang['Price']; ?></em><span>[<?php echo $config['currency_symbol']; ?>]</span>
              </td>
              <td class="quantity">
                <?php echo $lang['Quantity']; ?>
              </td>
              <td class="summary">
                <em><?php echo $lang['Summary']; ?></em><span>[<?php echo $config['currency_symbol']; ?>]</span>
```

Comment: where and how is `$lang` populated from?

Comment: I don't exactly know. I got this as a template and need to code further. But what I can tell is that if there is a variable, it is always $lang["here the name of the variable"]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate `$lang['Name']` in `<?php ... ?>` tags, and `echo` it.

```
<a href="step-3.php?orderName=<?php echo $lang['Name']; ?>">YOUR LINK TEXT</a>
```

Comment: Ah wanna say I tried that too the results were the same. 

I tried this one and the one above without any success unfortunately

Comment: There's probably something wrong with `$lang['Name']`, so first check what it is showing. Then do `ctrl+u`(or `cmd+u` for Mac) to see the source code, and check whether you have the right link there or not.

Comment: Rajdeep is correct. If that doesn't work, I think you'll need to show more code.

Comment: edited. In one of these I put the code that should work but doesn't somehow

Comment: What does the code that links to this page look like? Looking at what you said you tried `<a href='step-3.php?orderName =$lang['Name']'></a>` has a space between `orderName` and the `=`, that's no good.